# NGRX - spread operator remove atribute instead of replace in reducer

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, reducers

In my reducer I am trying to merge current state with value pased trought action. But problem is that merge operation remove object atribut instead of updating it.
I am using:

```
    on(WineActions.SetCurrentWine, (state, data) => {
        const newState = deepCopy(state);
        return {
            ...newState,
            currentWine: {...newState.currentWine, ...data}
        };
    }),
    ...
    export function deepCopy(state) {
       return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
    }
```

- ionic cli 6.9.1
- angular 8.2.14
- ngrx/store 8.6.0
- ngrx/store-devtools 8.6.0

[Action snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VULH5.png)
[Diff snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCMkt.png)

Thank to all of you!!!!

Edit:
I did went trough whole reducer and find out that problem was initialize action... I hate that I do not know why merge does not work but it is working now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing - never do deep copy, only update the value you need.

if you want `data` to replace `currentWine`, do like that.

```js
    on(WineActions.SetCurrentWine, (state, data) => {
        return {
            ...state,
            currentWine: data,
        };
    }),
```

and nothing else.

Comment: Why not? I read in documentation that state shold be change in inmutable way...

Comment: It should be changed in an inmutable way, but you should change only required nodes, not everything. Because if you change what shouldn't be changed it triggers selectors and causes redundant rerenders.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the spread operation overwrites the actual update. Should not it be like:

```js
currentWine: {
   ...newState.currentWine,
   ...data,
   wineColor: newState.currentWine.wineColor,
}
```

Comment: I did test it and it does not work .... Still Thank you !!!!!!

Comment: sorry for line typo. I did edit the response. Can you try it out again? because I still think its mapping issue